# Grep outputs entire searched file

Tags: grep, bioinformatics

I'm currently trying to parse the following file type (.fasta):

```
>SeqID=0001__GroupID=0001
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0002__GroupID=0001
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0003__GroupID=0002
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0004__GroupID=0003
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0005__GroupID=0003
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0006__GroupID=0004
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
```

To extract sequences by their group IDs. I have a file of the IDs to extract in the following format:

```
GroupID=0002
GroupID=0003
```

I've been using the following command:

```
$ grep -A 1 -f groupIDs_to_extract.txt sequences_file.fasta > output.txt
```

The idea being to perform a grep with each ID in the input text file, with the following line of context included to actually extract the sequence. So, from my example, the output would be all sequences from group 2 and 3:

```
>SeqID=0003__GroupID=0002
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0004__GroupID=0003
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0005__GroupID=0003
ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
```

However, it just outputs the entire sequences_file.fasta at the end, and I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `grep -A 1` supported in your `grep` binary?

Comment: You probably have a blank line in `groupIDs_to_extract.txt` (at the end of the file, most likely). Blank lines mean "match everything".

Comment: I have realised that my file was not actually formatted as I thought (see my answer). However, yes, I did have a blank line in my `groupIDs_to_extract.txt`. Only once I fixed both did it work, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my file was actually formatted as follows:

```
>SeqID=0001__GroupID=0001 ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0002__GroupID=0001 ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0003__GroupID=0002 ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
>SeqID=0004__GroupID=0003 ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC
```

I didn't notice as my text editor (gedit) wrapped the text, so it looked like a normal .fasta file.

I used a regex find + replace to add newlines in to format it correctly, and now the grep works as intended.

As an aside, I altered the end of the command:

```
$ grep -A 1 -f groupIDs_to_extract.txt sequences_file.fasta | grep -v "\--" > output.txt
```

So that it removed the -- that grep sticks in if you use the context command.